# Center text inside an input button

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input button with text inside - I want that the text will fit the input button (meaning, if it doesnt fit, it will spread on 2 or 3 rows).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.blankbtn
{
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
background-image: url(http://thumbnails.billiondigital.com/200/930200/794615_small_checkboard.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
 
}
</style>
<input type="button" value="heres a long text" class="blankbtn"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

add this css

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Thanx ,I tried it on chrome and it works , but it doesn't work for me on IE11 browser

Answer (score 0):

Use white-space:normal;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.blankbtn
{
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
background-image: url(http://thumbnails.billiondigital.com/200/930200/794615_small_checkboard.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
  white-space: normal;
 
}
</style>
<input type="button" value="heres a long text" class="blankbtn"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want but it doesn't work for me (maybe it's related to the browser? IE11)?

Comment: It's not relevant to use chrome because my company works only with IE11 now.
I tried your code snippet here on chrome and it works but not on my work station

Comment: OK fine I will look into it

Comment: white-space: pre-wrap;  try this instead of white-space:normal ; , say whether its working , i am not able to simulate it since i dont have IE11. If it is working upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
```

it works in IE. see here **[white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)** scroll down to **Browser compatibility**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.blankbtn
{
text-align:center;
font-size:20px;
width:150px;
height:150px;
background-image: url(http://thumbnails.billiondigital.com/200/930200/794615_small_checkboard.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
 
}
</style>
<input type="button" value="heres a long text" class="blankbtn"/>

</body>
</html>
```